# Why Git is not showing merge conflicts when a deleted file in branch is merged with master that has that file

Tags: git, github, merge

In Master Git there is **Core-src.A** and **Feature1-src.B**. 
Then a new Branch is created and in that branch **Core-src** folder is deleted and also a new file is created **Feature1-src.New**.

.
Now when we merge the branch to master, Master which was previously having **Core-src** folder is deleted.

What i expected was a merge conflict to be thrown in Windows Git GUI.

//Edit-sub Question
Is there any way to Protect a certain folder **Core-src**  from any modifications from the branches.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason there would be a conflict: when you merge in `master`, your bring the change "delete `src`", so it's just applied.

There would likely have been a conflict if you created a file in this `src` directory on the `master` branch before the merge. Because the merge would have had to handled the conflicting changes:

- delete `src`
- add a file in `src`

Comment: what is another graceful method to prevent branch from deleting the `src` folder. is there any way before creating a branch i could inform it to ignore `src`.

Comment: its absurd that it works this way, that the branch may not always need all the files as its master, and just bcoz master needs its imp ortant files it should keep modifing those files to prevent branch from deleting it.

Comment: Who deleted `src`? and who merged? You, or another contributor? If it's you, then there's not much you can do to prevent yourself from deleting stuff. If it's not you, just remove the permission to other users!

Answer (score 2):

If `src` was deleted in `branchA`, then when merging that branch to `master`, there can be conflicts if `master` has changed `src`, for example in any of the following ways:

- changed a file in `src`
- added a file in `src`
- changed permission of a file in `src`
- renamed `src`

And maybe others too. If no change happened in `master` on `src` that would conflict with `src` getting deleted, then the merge will succeed normally.

By default Git commits the merge. If you want to avoid that (so that you can review the changes first), you can use this command:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff branchA
```

This will perform the merge, but will not commit. At this point, if you notice that `src` got deleted, you could bring it back before committing, with the command:

```
git checkout HEAD -- src
```

Finally, it's strange that somebody would create a file in `target`, which is usually used for build products and should not be under version control. This usually happens by mistake when `target` is not listed in `.gitignore`.

Comment: dont mind the naming used to illustrate the situation.

Comment: This provides some resolution to bring the file back. Is there any way we can protect certain files from modification or deletion from merging from the branches. Say a `core-src` and i dont want any changes by merging from a branch which has done main work on 'Feature1-src', no matter whatever changes they might have done in `core-src` in branch.

Comment: For that, I know of this method: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies -- I've never used or tested it though. Good luck!